# Oracle APEX - Export a query into CSV using a button

Tags: oracle, oracle-apex

I have a button on an apex page that should allow the user to export data (based on a query not seen by the end user) into a CSV file.

How to link this button to my query so we can export the result into a CSV file?

Thanks

Comment: Just to be clear, the query results you want to export are *not* displayed on the page, right?  Otherwise, you'd use the standard functionality for a classic report.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to Scott Spendolini, I use his link: https://spendolini.blogspot.fr/2006/04/custom-export-to-csv.html

I simply create a Report Region with my query. Add a button which will get you to a blank page that I created. On that page, I added a PL/SQL process which will fire "**On Load - Before Header**" In the source of that process, I use this code:

```
begin
-- Set the MIME type
owa_util.mime_header( 'application/octet', FALSE );
-- Set the name of the file
htp.p('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="emp.csv"');
-- Close the HTTP Header
owa_util.http_header_close;
-- Loop through all rows in EMP
for x in (select e.ename, e.empno, d.dname
from emp e, dept d where e.deptno = d.deptno
  and e.deptno like :P1_DEPTNO)
loop
 -- Print out a portion of a row,
 -- separated by commas and ended by a CR
 htp.prn(x.ename ||','|| x.empno ||','||
         x.dname || chr(13));
end loop;
-- Send an error code so that the
-- rest of the HTML does not render
htmldb_application.g_unrecoverable_error := true;
end;
```

Comment: My solution does the same thing with one line of JavaScript.

Comment: I like the simplicity of this solution but it does NOT handle escaping data that contains the delimiter character(s) so the downloaded CSV may be malformed.

Answer (score 8):

I did this once by defining a region on the page with condition=never, but you can still invoke the download with the relevant URL, which you can farm from the "download as CSV" link when the region *is* visible by using the Inspect Element feature of your browser.

[image]

You'll see the request is the region ID with a prefix.
So you can use this invoke a download

```
/ords/f?p=your_app:your_page:your_session:FLOW_EXCEL_OUTPUT_R571755827567965848_en
```

or have your button call the same JavaScript

```
window.location.href=apex.server.url({p_request: 'FLOW_EXCEL_OUTPUT_R571755827567965848_en'},2);
```

This will work even if the region condition is Never.

Comment: Where can I get the URL?

Comment: answer expanded

Comment: Thank you for the reply, I dont display the query results I want to export in the page.

Comment: Exactly as I've described

Answer (score 0):

The same code I use in my page before header process ,its working fine . The issue is I have 3 process , each process RUN on different Condition e.g if :P12_reg_id=11 then the process-1 ,if :P12_reg_id=12 the process-2 will execute and download the CSv.

i put condtion in process server side condition but only first process is downloading .

any suggestion please

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient reputation you will be able to comment on any post.
Please do not comment in the answer and take the tour and read How to Answer: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer
If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking Ask Question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask.
You can also add a bounty to draw more attention to this question once you have enough reputation: https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/set-bounties