# How to export PLSQL Dynamic Content Table to Excel File?

Tags: oracle-apex, apex, apex-code, oracle-apex-5.1, oracle-apex-5

I have created an HTML table region using PLSQL Dynamic Content, and I want to create a button that exports or converts the region content (HTML TABLE) to an Excel file. Is that possible or not? Can someone give me an idea of how to make this possible?

Comment: If you're on an a version of apex 20.2 or higher then you can use the [APEX_DATA_EXPORT] api.(https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/apex/22.2/aeapi/APEX_DATA_EXPORT.html)

Comment: I use Application Express 5.1 version

Comment: Do upgrade - working on an old version of apex is not productive. Anyway, have a look here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50374730/oracle-apex-export-a-query-into-csv-using-a-button . That is pretty much the only way I know of (I mean that link to scott spendolini's blog)